# Problems with running py scripts from cmd

Tags: python, cmd

I have recently installed another Python without deleting previous and now when I am trying to run my script from cmd, Windows pushing me to choose the app that will run py.script.

Comment: You have to set the PATH variable to point to the right python executable.

Comment: Some more information might aid to properly help you. Like how exactly are you running and what error exactly you are getting, to start with

Comment: actually i don't have any erorrs but when i turn on cmd and write the path of my folder with scripts, then i typing name.py and windows push me to choose aplication that will run th script

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/x75Y792.png                 https://i.imgur.com/qv3XJrM.png

Comment: @Tomerikoo hey, i just there pinned some photos with the problem process, will be very appreciate if you could help

Comment: the path is correct by the way

Comment: You should [edit] all that information, and any more you have, inside the question, not in comments. It will help other people coming here to get a clear view of your problem. Also try to avoid posting images or links to them. Whatever can be represented as text is better copied to the post as formatted text

Comment: if you want to run a script by calling it directly you should have the first line saying `#!usr/bin/python`. Otherwise you need to run it like `python name.py` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-the-usr-bin-env-python-shebang-on-the-first-line-of-a-pyt

Answer (score 0):

as alex067 stated, you have to set the PATH variable in your Environment Variables.

You can follow the instructions here https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path